# Batch script is not working as expected

Tags: batch-file

i am using this below script for testing my webservice more than a year and i found recently that it is not sending the alert if all the webservice failed

```
case 1:- if all the service pass(logs.txt) it send the UP Alert
Case 2:- if one or two service got failed(logs.txt) it sends the down alert
but if all the service got failed(logs.txt) it didn't send any(Up or Down) alert
```

please correct me if i do any mistakes, now it became a big issue for me

**script:-**

```
@echo on
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
REM set 
set mymail= "Superuser@gmail.com"   
pushd "c:\logs" || goto :eof

    set "tries=2"
    for /l %%a in (1 1 %tries%) do (
        >logs.txt (
            call resource.cmd
            Tester.exe  
        )
        echo The Tester returned errorlevel : !errorlevel! >>logs.txt
        if not errorlevel 1 (
            wmailto %mymail% -s"UP - WebServices Health Monitoring." -tlogs.txt"
            goto :eof
        )
        if %%a equ %tries% (
           wmailto %mymail% -s"DOWN - WebServices Health Monitoring." -tlogs.txt
        )
    )
```

**logs.txt**

```
CPU percentage: 0 %
Memory usage:   7 %

11/10/2017 1:25 PM

SOAP1 : <-- FAIL -->0.1249984 secs  
     Connection Error: Unable to connect to the remote server
SOAP2 : <-- FAIL -->0 secs  
     Unknown Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

XML1 : <-- FAIL -->0.015625 secs    
     Unknown Exception: Unable to connect to the remote server
XML2 : <-- FAIL -->0 secs   
     Unknown Exception: Unable to connect to the remote server

REST1 : <-- FAIL -->0.0156248 secs  
     Connection Error: Unable to connect to the remote server
REST2 : <-- FAIL -->0 secs  
     Connection Error: Unable to connect to the remote server
REST3 : <-- FAIL -->0 secs  
     Connection Error: Unable to connect to the remote server
REST4 : <-- FAIL -->0.0156247 secs  
     Connection Error: Unable to connect to the remote server
The Tester.exe returned errorlevel : 3
```

**New Script with changes :-**

```
@echo on
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
    REM set 
    set mymail= "Superuser@gmail.com"   
    pushd "c:\logs" || goto :eof

        set "tries=2"
        for /l %%a in (1 1 %tries%) do (
            >logs.txt (
                call resource.cmd
                Tester.exe  
            )
            echo The Tester returned errorlevel : !errorlevel! >>logs.txt
            if not errorlevel 1 (
                wmailto %mymail% -s"UP - WebServices Health Monitoring." -tlogs.txt"
                goto :eof
            )
        )
        wmailto %mymail% -s"DOWN - WebServices Health Monitoring." -tlogs.txt
```

Comment: which errorlevels does Tester.exe give at what conditions?

Comment: these are the error levels:
     0 - All tests passed
     1 - At least one test failed with response returned but values do not
 expected.
     2 - At least one test failed with error making web service call.
     3 - At least one test failed with general exception.
     4 - Service timed out before successful completion.
     21 - At least one test failed with service2 Issue detected.

Comment: i have tried using !errorlevel! and %errorlevel% and errorlevel but still the same issue, please help

Comment: should work, as far as I can tell. But my logic would be different: move the `DOWN` thing completely out of the loop (without any `if`), because if it's not `ÙP` for `%tries%` times, then it must be `DOWN`

Comment: if i move the DOWN out of the if then i am getting  down alert twice

Comment: another one out... Even out of the `for`

Comment: yes while testing it works fine after out of the for , can you please tell what could be the difference, because when i manually down the service it works but  in real time it wasn't. that is my concern